# loading method based on URL

Tags: php, model-view-controller, class, methods

I am trying to build a small mvc-based application.

How do I call a method in a class based on a query string?

For example, the $_GET query string is being set as load_master_form

```
http://www.domain.com/settings/load_master_form
```

And to call the method within the settings class, I am doing:

```
function __construct(){
    $this->{$_GET['method']}();
}
```

But obviously that doesn't work - it just isn't possible to load a method like that. So how would it be done?

Comment: you need to create a routing mechanism .. i guess [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12810899/727208) might help

Comment: are you sure you'd even want to do something like that? what's to stop a malicious user from doing `example.com?method=blow_up_the_universe`?

Comment: @Marc B, the class only loads public data, and if the method doesn't exist then it goes to a 404 page.

Comment: Do you know about Htaccess rewrite rule?. and also a question, is the settings is a folder or not.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this would work fine, as long as you have created the method for $_GET['method'], and you are using URI routing (.htaccess or whatever)

Generally I tend to call the method name in the URI -

```
// domain.com/class_name/method_name/params

class class_name{
    function __construct(){
        ...
    }
    function method_name(){
        ...
    }
// etc.
}
```

Comment: This is what I am trying to do right now, but my question is how do I load the method from the method_name uri?

Comment: why then you marked this as accepted answer ?

Comment: because it helped me figure it out...

Answer (score 0):

At first, you have to create and .htaccess file, to redirect all requests to a single file (usually index.php). The string that user inputs is then passed to php as an **GET** variable.

How to create .htaccess file is presented [here](http://codular.com/htaccess-introduction).

Then you have to decide upon structure of you MVC. Lets say you want every third argument in url(http://www.someting.com/first/second/third) to be a method. Then you would do something like this..

```
// Variables
$args = explode('/',$_GET['method']);

// Get method
$method = rtrim($args[1]);
```

This is just a diry solution..

Comment: even in simplest situation this would assume, that there always are at least two slashes in `$_GET['method`]. If you do not know the number of delimiters in the string, it is a good trick to add some additional ones at the end : `explode( '/', $_GET['method'] . '//' );` At least this way you can avoid unnecessary warnings .. if not actually solve the underlaying problems `=P`

Comment: there usually are in mvc frameworks..

Comment: `http://who.cares/` .. this link would produce you either 1 or 0 slashes (depends on URL rewrite details), which in turn might cause a warning, when you access the 2nd array element.

Comment: Actually i made a mistake in code, you would reach for array[1] not array[2]. You could check if array[0] exists, if true then you call a class, if array[1] you would call method in that class and so on. As i said, usuall pattern for mvc url is www.something.com/class/method/parameters

Comment: yes .. i updated comment accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use reflection, like so:

```
public static function doUserMethod($methodName)
{
    $reflectionMethod = new ReflectionMethod('YourUserMethodsClass', $methodName);
    return $reflectionMethod->invokeArgs(new YourUserMethodsClass(), array(/* Method Arguments Here */));
}
```

Which can then be called as:

```
YourClass::doUserMethod($_GET['method']);
```

The advantage of this is you can then limit users to only the methods in the specific class you specify (i.e. `YourUserMethodsClass` in my example). Obviously though, you'll need some special extra processing if your methods require parameters (unlike the example you gave).

Comment: Reflections are orders of magnitude slower then simple `method_exists()` and static call would mean that you decided to resort to procedural programming.